# The way to renovate Mage site (live -> develop -> live)

Tags: deploy

we have some live sites since Mage 1.4 and are now @ 1.7

We want to upgrade/renovate the site by adding new modules, removing old, and changing the theme + CSS. Now I have always been wondering what the (best) techique is to make a copy of a live site, make changes, copy back to live + update the orders that were made in the meantime.

1. LIVE SITE -> BACKUP SITE + BACKUP SQL
2. Install on WAMP? or COPY SITE URL?
3. Make changes
4. Export orders made in meantime in LIVE site and make full backup
5. OVERWRITE LIVE SITE PHP + SQL DB
6. Import the orders

**Is this the way to go?**

I read many articles on GIT etc, but our ISP doesnt offer thesse kind of service

Comment: Without version control, you are hard pressed to do anything effective, short of minor changes. There's a good git guide for Magento here, http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/our-magento-git-guide-and-work-flow/ . But you'll need to find a host that supports what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a live snapshot is a good way to start development. A thing you should make sure at this step is that real customers will not receive emails from your development site. There are a few ways to go:

- do not have a email server installed on your development server
- use a script that will replace all the customer emails with dummy ones
- On newer Magento versions, you can disable email communication - http://blog.ecommercesoftwaresolutionsonline.com/archives/861/how-to-disable-the-email-communication-in-magento.html

Now, for the step that brings you back the changes in production, you should never replace the production database with the dev one. This simply does not work. Here are just a few other things that may have changed in the meantime, besides the orders:

- customers
- product stocks
- invoices, shipments

The best way to port settings is to include them in code. When it comes to database changes, it usually boils down to adding/editing/deleting attributes and changing system settings. If you are unfamiliar with adding attributes via code, read http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/installing_custom_attributes_with_your_module .

Setting system config settings via code is easy too - http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/ . I usually have a "Settings" module that will do the changes programatically in setup files. I only need to bump the version & create the update script that changes the settings. Then I can push the code to how many environments I want and the settings will be applied.

In some cases, you may need to create static blocks, edit cms pages or other type of content. Every operation can be done by code too, but make a judgment call on whether it is faster to write all this code or just redo the changes in production.